# Grant permissions to a user, where the user can ALTER only the tables created by him in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

Say I have a set of tables in a schema named test, Now I want a new user who should be given access to this schema to do INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE and DELETE. Now I want to give permission to this user to CREATE new tables in the same schema and ALTER the ones which are created by the user alone, Whereas the user should not be able to ALTER the existing tables which are created by some other users or the postgres user.How this can be done in Postgresql 9.5.9.

Answer (score 0):

all requested is a "default" behaviour I believe, eg:

```
t=# create schema s1;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# alter schema s1 owner to u1;
ALTER SCHEMA
t=# set role u1;
SET
t=> create table s1.t1(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=> reset role;
RESET
t=# create user u2;
CREATE ROLE
t=# grant all on s1.t1 to u2;
GRANT
t=# grant usage on schema s1 to u2;
GRANT
t=# set role u2;
SET
t=> insert into s1.t1 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=> alter table s1.t1 add column n int;
ERROR:  must be owner of relation t1
t=# grant create on schema s1 to u2;
GRANT
t=> create table s1.t2 (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=> insert into s1.t2 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=> alter table s1.t2 add column n int;
ALTER TABLE
```

(all run as superuser)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself, the older tables which are already existing are created by some other user, hence the owner of the table will be the other user, Now I granted all privileges followed by grant usage on the schema, the new user is now able to alter only the tables created by him whereas the new user is not able to alter the tables that were created by some other user.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA schema_name to new_user_name;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name to new_user_name;

This worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue - wanted to create 3 users and a database for an app. Couldn't find an answer to wrote it up.

Here's the strategy:

1. As the main db user (postgres) create a app database, and the app database superadmin.
2. As the app superadmin, create other users, and grant them necessary permissions.
3. As main db user (postgres), revoke all create privileges except for app superadmin.

You can review the script at, and use it for yourself. A gist is available at below address:

https://gist.github.com/anilgulecha/99ea03e5b00b5ea90650c616d8cb2487